# Printing two pdf on one sheet without scaling

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf document which covers half of an A4 page. Is there a way to duplicate the text/images of that document, such that I get a single page A4 document (pdf file) with twice the orginal content, one above each other? Since the original only covers half a page, no scaling should be necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of pdfjam and pdftk to do this:

```
pdfjam --offset '0mm -148.5mm' half-a4.pdf --outfile other-a4.pdf
pdftk half-a4.pdf stamp other-a4.pdf output double.pdf
```

pdfjam is being used to shift the page down half a page (A4 = 297mm tall, and 297÷2=148.5). If you need to shift the other way, you'd use `-110mm 0mm`.

Then pdftk puts the two pages on top of each other.

[image: half A4 (original)]
[image: +]
[image: other half A4 (generated)]
[image: =]
[image: double (generated)]

Comment: This works well, however often when overlapping files with PDFTK there are two problems: 1) only two files at a time can be overlapped, so a multi-step process is needed; 2) most PDF files have a while "background" (actually a rectangle) which needs to be removed otherwise it may partially overlap the other objects from previous files. LibreOffice Draw can do the latter step fairly easily in most cases

Answer (score 1):

You can try the command `convert` as follows:

```
convert -density 300 -define pdf:fit-page=A4 <in.pdf> <out.pdf>
```

Another solution:

```
pdfjam --outfile <output.pdf> --paper a4paper <input.pdf>
```

Main man page is [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfjam)

Manual is [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf)

Download [here](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic/firth/software/pdfjam/pdfjam_latest.tgz)

Example commands are [here](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam)

Comment: This did not do anything. The output.pdf file looks the same as the input.

Comment: Did you try the command `convert` something like `convert -density 300 -define pdf:fit-page=A4 <in.pdf> <out.pdf>`

Comment: Yes, I tried both, and neither worked for me.

Comment: Same results here...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pdfjam --nup` to achieve this. This would put two pages onto one page at A4 size.

```shell
pdfjam --nup 1x2 --papersize '{210mm,297mm}' input.pdf
```

If you wanted to ensure no scaling, that could be added to the command like so:

```shell
pdfjam --nup 1x2 --papersize '{210mm,297mm}' --noautoscale true input.pdf
```

Note that it's unclear if the document in question is A4 size with half of each page containing content and the rest being blank or if each page is half the size of an A4 sheet and filled with content. This solution is for the latter.

Comment: Adminbee edited my answer to the exact thing and downvoted me?